# Initialize an array where the second dimension adds an arbirtrary number of values with append

Tags: python, arrays

How to initialize an array whose first dimension is fixed (say 5) but the second dimension may vary. For example, we create an array `arr` with five entries and then we add some element, e.g. to `arr[1]` by appending some value, and then to `arr[2]`, and then again we append to `arr[1]`, etc.

Comment: Probably better to use a list if you need to append frequently and the different lists have different lengths.

Comment: What exactly do we mean by array here? A python list, a python array, or a numpy array?

Comment: And what should the output look like? There's talk of appending but you could probably just generate in one go with numpy (though the second dimension would be fixed once the random size had been chosen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a 2D list here to make your life easier

```
#Define the list
a = [[],[]]
#Add 5 elements to both sublists
for i in range(6):
    a[0].append(i)
    a[1].append(i)
print(a)
#[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
#Add more elements to 2nd sublist
a[1].append(6)
a[1].append(7)
print(a)
#[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```